# Смена направления разработки

Tags: android, 1с, задание-на-собеседовании

Мой вопрос касается карьеры программиста. Я слышал от некоторых программистов-блогеров, что за свою карьеру программист может несколько раз сменить направление разработки.
Я сейчас только начинаю работать в этой сфере и мне интересно, как это происходит. Допустим есть 1С разработчик, с 2 годами опыта работы на предприятии. И в один момент он решает перейти в разработку под Android. Языками и нужным стеком технологии, допустим, он обладает, но производственного опыта в этом направлении у него нет. Придётся ли ему всё начинать с начала или имеющийся производственный опыт сыграет свою роль?

А также как насчёт тех, кто имеет 5-10 лет опыта работы программистом и также меняет направление?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1C эта не та область, которая может стать хоть какой-то базой для перехода в мобильную разработку. Хотите менять область, ловите технологию на взлете, если повезет, попадете в майнстрим. Еще не так давно Flutter был таким направлением.

Comment: Как это происходит? Обыкновенно. Опыт поможет? Любой опыт и знания помогают.

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация следующая: при смене стека, как правило человек начинает с самой низшей ступени (джуниор). Само собой платить ему будут как джуниору, т.е. по минимуму. То что при этом у работника есть опыт - будет плюсом, но на зп не отразится. Примерно через 1-3 месяца работы, - становится абсолютно ясно есть у сотрудника перспективы или нет.

Исключения из этого сценария конечно возможны.

Comment: сеньор не пойдет джуном. это не нужно ни ему, ни работодателю. сходит в отпуск для самообразования и будет мидлом в худшем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Программист с опытом хотя бы в общих чертах знает и умеет пользоваться следующим:

- системы контроля версий и таск-трекеры,
- тестирование (модульное, интеграционное),
- профилирование и отладка,
- логирование,
- алгоритмы,
- паттерны проектирования, принципы SOLID,
- общие знания архитектуры приложений,
- общие знания устройства компьютеров, сетей, операционных систем,
- умение понимать, чего хочет клиент, начальник, коллега,
- умение самостоятельно искать информацию,
- и многое другое...

При переходе на другой стек почти все эти знания пригодятся.
Останется лишь освоить синтаксис нового языка программирования, причём любой продвинутый редактор текста будет помогать в этом, подсвечивая ошибки. И освоить модные в этом сезоне фреймворки. Да, это тоже немало, но быстрее, чем с полного нуля.

Comment: Уточняющий вопрос: будучи ведущим инженером (аналог Senior) в 1С или, к примеру, Senior-ом в каком нибудь направлении веб-разработки, реально ли быстро дорасти хотя бы до мидла? И насколько быстро можно дорасти до мидла, если занимал аналогичную позицию в 1С, веб и т.д.?

Comment: насколько быстро можно дорасти до мидла ? довольно быстро на мой взгляд думаю за 6 мес максимум; Основная проблема не в этом; Понятно что программист 1С (если он именно программист а не консультант) готов писать код на другом языке. Проблема в том, чтобы всё удачно сложилось, а именно контора нуждалась в мидле, готова была платить, не перегружала бы работой, отпуск, премия и т.д и т.п.